# Tracking program that sporadically opens ports

Tags: debian, iptables, ntp, udp

On a Debian server I manage, I have a iptables whitelist firewall.  For some reason, one process seems to be sending a bunch of unauthorized packets, but I can't seem to identify which one.

```
[1624382.821400] IPTables-Dropped: No Match: IN= OUT=enp2s5 SRC=10.0.6.164 DST=198.60.22.240 LEN=76 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=49824 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=59084 DPT=123 LEN=56 
[1624382.821625] IPTables-Dropped: No Match: IN= OUT=enp2s5 SRC=10.0.6.164 DST=209.208.79.69 LEN=76 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=2620 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=60835 DPT=123 LEN=56 
[1624382.821836] IPTables-Dropped: No Match: IN= OUT=enp2s5 SRC=10.0.6.164 DST=35.238.255.157 LEN=76 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22984 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=39290 DPT=123 LEN=56 
[1624382.822042] IPTables-Dropped: No Match: IN= OUT=enp2s5 SRC=10.0.6.164 DST=129.250.35.251 LEN=76 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=39284 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=53528 DPT=123 LEN=56 
[1624413.404586] IPTables-Dropped: No Match: IN= OUT=enp2s5 SRC=10.0.6.164 DST=34.225.6.20 LEN=76 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=59854 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=51331 DPT=123 LEN=56
```

I've [looked it up](https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=123) and it seems like something is trying to use NTP, which is weird since I don't recall setting anything up to use that.  I assume Debian must have something installed by default but I can't find any documentation on it.

It always sends 5 udp packets every 20-30 minutes.  Always to different IP addresses.  I want to figure out which program is sending these packets so I can either trust or remove it.  I tried hacking together a script but it didn't seem to capture anything:

```
sudo tcpdump | grep ntp > 123.log &
```

Anyone know what I can do to figure out what's sending these packets?

Comment: Have you tried looking at running processes?

Comment: I have, and there's nothing explicitly named such that it would imply ntp.  I'll admit I don't know every process running on the computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traffic on UDP to a destination port 123 is most likely related to the NTP protocol.
Names to check for on the process list my not only include `ntpd` but also `chrony`, `systemd-timesyncd` as well as other ntp clients.

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html.en

As the SPT (source port) varies and the DPT (destination port) is stable, it can be assumed that the related program is a NTP client. But it may as well be a ntp server, which syncs to the higher level stratum servers.

Comment: Found it!  It was systemd-timesyncd.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad to have had the right name on my short list of ntp clients. :)